# Why is this functor being described as a family of objects?

Tags: category-theory, functors

Picture below from Mac Lane's Category Theory:

Why is this description of objects of the category $C^X$ valid?

By definition of the functor category it should be Objects : Functors $F,G,H, ... :X \rightarrow C $ and Arrows: $\tau, \tau' ...: F \rightarrow G$ as natural transformations.

Where the functors $F=(\text{F}_{\text{ob}}, \text{F$_{\text{arr}}$})$ have $F_{ob} : x \rightarrow F(x) \in C$ and $F(1_x) = 1_{F(x)}$ (since the only arrows in $x$ are the identity arrows).

So it would seem that the objects of $C^X$ are $\{F(x) \in C : x \in X, F \in \text{Funct}(X,C)\}$

But why is the below image description of the objects of $C^X$ a valid description?

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object of $C^X$ is indeed a functor $X\rightarrow C$. However, think about what a functor from $X$ to $C$ is. Since $X$ is the discrete category, a functor $F:X\rightarrow C$ is entirely determined by what objects of $C$ it sends the objects of $F$ to: if $F_0, F_1$ are functors from $X$ to $C$ such that for all $x\in Ob(X)$ we have $F_0(x)=F_1(x)$, then in fact $F_0=F_1$. (Note that this is extremely false in general.)

So a functor $F: X\rightarrow C$ is essentially just the indexed family $\{a_x: x\in X, a_x=F(x)\}$: each completely determines the other. (This may get a bit more intuitive when you remember that set-theoretically, we generally think of a function as the corresponding set of ordered pairs - maybe we also explicitly add the codomain to this data, but in our case the codomain of the functor is always $C$, so we don't need to.) Moreover, **any** indexed family $\{a_x: x\in X\}$ corresponds to a functor $X\rightarrow C$. So it is in fact perfectly fine (if slightly notation-abusive) to say that the objects of $C^X$ are exactly the indexed families $\{a_x: x\in X\}$, since each such indexed set determines a unique functor and each functor corresponds to a unique such indexed family.

---

Note that the *indexing* here is important: the *range* of $F$ isn't enough to determine $F$, we need to keep track of *which* object of $X$ go to a given object of $C$.

So you really want to think of an indexed family as a family of *ordered pairs*.

Comment: So what exactly would be the constant family here then?  As in the diagonal functor defined in the image.  Just a functor $H$ that maps each $x$ to $c$?

Comment: @OliverG Yup. Given an object $c\in C$, the corresponding functor $\Delta_c$ maps every element of $X$ to $c$.

Comment: You used the word "essentially" as a relationship between the functors and the classes, is there a concrete explanation of what you mean by essentially?  As in how did you get from functors to classes?  Is it basically "these are bijective/isomorphic so we're using these instead because it's a better intuitive representation of what I'm trying to convey"?

Comment: @OliverG I meant exactly what I wrote: "each such indexed set determines a unique functor and each functor corresponds to a unique such indexed family." If you prefer, you can think about the corresponding indexed family as an *invariant assigned to* the functor, and the point is that this assignment of invariants is bijective and so we can reason about the functors by reasoning about the invariants.

Comment: Here's a silly example of such reasoning: suppose $X$ has five objects and $C$ has $12$. Then we know that $C^X$ has $12^5$ objects, since that's how many such indexed families there are. Even though the indexed family isn't literally the same as the corresponding functor - the latter has the additional data of which morphisms go where, even though that data is trivial in the sense of being completely determined by the functor's action on objects alone - we can draw a conclusion about the latter by analyzing the former. (We could also do the converse, but that doesn't seem to be useful.)

Answer (score 1):

A set $X$ can be turned into a (discrete) category by taking the elements of $X$ to be the objects and by taking only identities as morphisms.

With this identification, functors $X \to \mathcal{C}$ correspond exactly with $X$-indexed families of objects of $\mathcal{C}$; the action on morphisms is determined by the fact that the only morphisms of $X$ are identities.

Natural transformations between functors $X \to \mathcal{C}$ then correspond with $X$-indexed families of morphisms: the naturality condition is satisfied trivially again since the only morphisms in $X$ are identities.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a set, then an $X$-indexed family of objects of $C$ is *by definition* a function $a$ that associates to any element $x$ of $X$ an object $a_x$ of $C$. It is *not* simply a set of objects of $C$ with the same cardinality as $X$.

Comment: So the notation $\{a_x : x \in X\}$ is not referring to a set but a function $a : X \rightarrow C$ by $ a : x \mapsto a_x \in C$?

Comment: Exactly. It may be confusing, but it's standard notation.